# Update multiple documents

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I want to update multiple documents in elasticsearch.
The update should correspond the SQL query

```
UPDATE tablename SET expired=true where id not in (list_of_ids)
```

Is it possible, or do you recommend different solution of keeping track of active and inactive documents?

I want to keep and use inactive documents to statistic purposes.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be easily done with the [update by query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html), like this:

```
POST index/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.expired = true"
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": {
        "ids": {
          "values": [1, 2, 3, 4]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks,  thats the solution. In Python with elasticsearch I just had to execute
`es.update_by_query(index, doctype, body)` where body is json you provided..